# Deletes all lines containing a specified word

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, cpu-word

I want to write a shell script which will delete all lines containing a specified word in one or more files supplied as arguments to it.How can i do it?

I am a beginner in shell script.So if you give answer with **details about how it works**, it will be very helpful.

Comment: This has to be a duplicate of something. You'll want to use `sed`. Something like `sed '/magicword/d' file`.

Comment: Saying something is a dupe without checking doesn't help.

Comment: Thanks for tracking that guy down. Added a flag as well. Tanvir Rahman, this site has a lot of answers all over the place, especially for actions that you suspect are not rare. Try using the Search box, or alternately, your question + stackoverflow in a Google search.

Comment: This sounds like a homework question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sed](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x23170.html) delete command will do this easily:

```
$ cat foo.txt 
apple
pear
peach
banana
orange

$sed -ie '/pea/d' foo.txt

$ cat foo.txt 
apple
banana
orange
```

This just searches for `pea` and deletes it with the `d` (delete) command.